# jsPlumb positioning the boxes automatically

Tags: javascript, css, jsplumb

I'm fairly new to jsPlumb and I was wondering if there's a way for the boxes/divs (the boxes that get connected to each other) to be automatically positioned in the page. I have a lot of "entities" which will be dynamically fetched from a database, so "manual" positioning is really not an option here. It doesn't matter where they are as long as they are not overlapping each other.

From what I've searched until now, jsPlumb has no documentation regarding this matter. I'm not sure how I would achieve some proper positioning of my boxes.

From the example below you  can see that the positioning of the boxes is taken care of manually by writing a bunch of CSS for each box - I definitely do not need that:

```
#window1 { top:30em;left:10em;}
#window2 { top:-2em; left:36em;}
#window3 { top:20em;left:45em; }
#window4 { top:17em; left:22em;}
```

Example: http://www.lively-kernel.org/repository/webwerkstatt/users/tmohr/libs/jsPlumb/demo/jquery/flowchartConnectorsDemo.html#

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/evycd00u/3

Answer (score 0):

The position is CSS. So you could use Javascript or JQuery to set the position of your boxes using some process:

```
// e.g. this uses JQuery
for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    $("#window"+i).css({top: 50+80*i, left: 200});
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be part of jsPlumb? I mean, if I do the positioning myself, I can just skip the library altogether... Thanks a lot for your answer though!

Comment: @aborted JSPlumb's main advantage is to maintain the connectors - you can put endpoints on the elements and let it draw the connections / manage the interactions. The elements are just divs, which means you can handle them directly in HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: I just tried applying the solution as you suggested, but the positioning just gets messy and the connectors can't find their target. It leads to the connector starting at the correct place, but leading nowhere. Also, I'd like the positioning to look somewhat like in the link above. I'd really appreciate your help as I'm really unfamiliar with this library.

Comment: @Aborted we need more code to work out why. EndPoints (where the connectors go) are positioned relative to the elements they belong to, but maybe there is something that places them wrong. Also, if the points move or the window changes size, you might have to repaint the element. If you're staying stuck, make a part of your work in a JSFiddle to share.

Comment: There you go: https://jsfiddle.net/evycd00u/3/ - Thanks for your help! For now I have been attempting to use the CSS from the URL I put in the question and make it look similar to that, but I'm really stuck with this positioning.

Comment: Is there possibly any other library which I could with a combination with jsPlumb which takes care of the positioning? Any help would be appreciated.